# How System.Type in class in C# work?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

As **System.Type** class is used for reflection. And most of members defined in **System.Type** is **abstract**.
In this code **FullName** property is used to get the class name, which is declared as abstract in **System.Type**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class MyClass
    {
        int val;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t = typeof(MyClass);
            Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Where is **FullName** implementation ??

---

Update: Here is how it **System.Type** defines

```
    public abstract string FullName { get; }
```

but it is abstract so where is actual implementation of this property

Comment: even if it is abstract, your class is still a Type and still has a name.  not clear what exactly you are asking

Comment: FullName is abstract in System.Type so we can't use it without implementing. I am asking where it gets implemented

Comment: The General truth IS: methods from abstract classes are implemented in classes which derive from abstract class. Abstract class can have both abstract and concrete methods. You can implement an interface inside the class, but the class itself is always "implemented".

Comment: @Cody I think it is a problem of wording. It is implemented in the namespace System inside the Type named "Type". So if you Ctrl and click on the property "Fullname" or click on it and hit F12 you should see the implementation of it.

Comment: @sprinter252 FullName is implemented as abstract in System.Type so still need to get implemented in derived class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call `t.GetType()`, you'll find the actual implementation returned by `typeof()` is in this case the internal class `System.RuntimeType`, source available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs#0d48ca51b2d2f8ed#references).

Comment: Where is GetType() implemenation ??

Comment: GetType() is implemented in [Object](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) and that implementation is marked extern and calls the CLR. Use [IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/) if you want to dig into hidden implementation details

Comment: @rene As System.Type is abstract and so is FullName property , so how the above code works, where is the actual implementation of FullName property of System.Type. ?


Is CLR providing code for this

Comment: @Cody, as CodeCaster indicated, RuntimeType implements FullName property.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa How can i view it ??

Comment: @Cody: Well, he did give you source in his answer. Just open the link and ctrl+f for "FullName".